# Add formula terms programmatically

Tags: r, regression

I am running a simulation and need to test the performance of different sized formulas. Drawing from  data frame with columns V1, V2, V3... Vk, I need to programmatically create formulas like `fit <- ols(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3, data=dataframe)` and so forth.

How can I code the formula to be able to scale the length of the formula?

Comment: Can you do `ols(y ~ .)`?

Comment: @BlueMagister I had the same idea, but when creating an example using `ols(y ~ . , data=dat)`, it threw an error because `terms.formula` doesn't get passed the data argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert text to a formula:

```
vars <- c(1, 2, 4)
formula.text <- paste0("y ~ V", paste(vars, collapse=" + V"))
formula.text
# [1] "y ~ V1 + V2 + V4"

library(rms)
fit <- ols(as.formula(formula.text), data=dataframe)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `reformulate`:

```
k <- 4

reformulate(paste0("V", seq(k)), response = "y")
# y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4
```