# specify model with selected terms using lm

Tags: r, linear-regression

A pretty straightforward for those with intimate knowledge of R

```
full <- lm(hello~., hellow)
```

In the above specification, linear regression is being used and hello is being modeled against all variables in dataset `hellow`.

I have 33 variables in `hellow`; I wish to specify some of those as independent variable. These variables have names that carry a meaning so I really don't want to rename them to `x1` `x2` etc.

How can I, without having to type the individual names of the variables (since that is pretty tedious), specify a select number of variables from the whole bunch?

I tried

```
full <- lm(hello~hellow[,c(2,5:9)]., hellow)
```

but it gave me an error `"Error in model.frame.default(formula = hello ~ hellow[,  :   invalid type (list) for variable 'hellow[, c(2, 5:9)]'`

Comment: closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253688/add-formula-terms-programmatically/22254121#22254121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reformulate` will construct a formula given the names of the variables, so something like:

(Construct data first):

```
set.seed(101)
hellow <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol=10)),
                   c("hello",paste0("v",1:9)))
```

Now run the code:

```
ff <- reformulate(names(hellow)[c(2,5,9)],response="hello")
full <- lm(ff, data=hellow)
```

should work.  (Works fine with this example.)

An easier solution just occurred to me; just select the columns/variables you want first:

```
hellow_red <- hellow[,c(1,2,5,9)]
full2 <- lm(hello~., data=hellow_red)
all.equal(coef(full),coef(full2))  ## TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this error : Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'hello    ' not found"

Comment: do you have a `hello` variable in your data set `hellow` ???  Probably can't help resolve this without a reproducible example ...

Comment: Yes, absolutely - I have hello in hellow as a variable. What do you mean reproducible example? Isn't the code considered reproducible example?

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is one that is self-contained, so that other people can actually run it and get the same error you're seeing.  Remote debugging is really hard.

Comment: Thanks alot again. Both solutions work. I had made a specification error which was mucking up the code.